# Non-user base TokenAuthentication for django-rest-framework

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework, api-key

I'm trying to create an api with token authentiaction. My problem is that I don't want tokens to be associated with user accounts but rather an account model.

For example:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    slug =      models.SlugField()
    name =      models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website =   models.URLField(blank=True, default='')
    members =   models.ManyToManyField(User, through='AccountMember')

class AccountMember(models.Model):
    ADMIN       = 1
    MANAGER     = 2
    MEMBER      = 3
    ROLES = (
        (ADMIN,     'administrator'),
        (MANAGER,   'manager'),
        (MEMBER,    'member'),
    )
    user =          models.ForeignKey(User)
    account =       models.ForeignKey(Account)
    role =          models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLES)
    date_joined =   models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Token(models.Model):
    """
    The default authorization token model.
    """
    key = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='auth_tokens')
    only_allowed_ips = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ip_list = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see, there are multiple users associated with an account so assigning the token to them would be useless.

I also want to be able to add multiple tokens to an account.

Does anyone know the best way I could add authentication/permissions to a system like this?

Answer (score 1):

You must replicate the following classes:

django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend: to check for auth and permissions 
 django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware: to set your Account linked with the request

probably you must create another django.contrib.auth.models.Permission to store your Account related permissions

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the problem myself. What I decided to do is too duplicate django rest framework's **authtoken module** in my application and to apply my own modifications.

You can copy the folder from DRF's repository in your own application's folder. Be sure to change related fields in your *settings.py*, *application/authtoken/admin.py* and of course in your *application/authtoken/models.py*